# Counting Java @author annotations per developer

Tags: java, annotations, author

I have a code base where developers use @author annotations on their class definitions. Is there a way for me to be able to programmatically count how many classes are authored by each developer using those annotations?

Comment: Are you sure the @author are annotations, and not doclets (tags that appear in the javadoc) ?

Comment: Great question. Now that I think about it, both scenarios can occur 1) @author in the javadoc and 2) @author annotations. It seems that the doclet scenario happens more often. Does that change the solution?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this is how you use the annotation

```
@Author("fred")
public class MyClass {...
```

Then here is a method that will do it

```
public List<Class> getClassesWrittenBy(String name, List<Class> classList) {
   List<Class> list = new LinkedList<Class>();
   for (Class clazz: classList)
      if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(Author.class)) {
          Author author = clazz.getAnnotation(Author.class);
          if (author.value().equals(name))
             list.add(clazz);
      }
   return (list);
}
```

Comment: No reason. Could (Should) have used a Set.

Comment: Does the solution change if doclets are used?

Comment: doclets are not annotations (in the programming sense). You will probably have to write your doclet plugins to process that or good old fashion grep